# Unicode regular expression in Java

Tags: android

I need to write a regular expression in Java which covers the following scenarios

Between 6-10 characters

Must be at least one numeral

I have been told that I should use Unicode convention in the regular expression as the input may be in many languages

Can anyone help?

Comment: There are only a very few chances that you can get help here because you haven't shown what you have tried so far. You need to include your effort along with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For string length, just use the `.length()` method. For matching, use `\p{Digit}`, this should do what you want and covers more than `\d` (although I fail to see what).

So:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}");

//...

if (input.length() < 6 || input.length() > 10)
    //fail
if (!p.matcher(input).find())
    //fail

// Success!
```

Comment: Will use .length()

The following failed


    `public class PasscodeValidator {

    final static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}");
 
 public static boolean validatePasscode(String passcode) {
  return p.matcher(passcode).lookingAt();
 }
 
 public static void main(String [] args) {
  System.out.println(validatePasscode("b1"));
 }
}`

Any idea?

Comment: Argh! It should be `.find()`, not `.lookingAt()`! Answer edited accordingly.